On the Background Independence condition
In General Relativity, one has that the equations of motion for any matter distribution are given by extremizing the following action:
\begin{equation}
 S[g] = \int\left[\frac{1}{8\pi}(R - 2\Lambda) + \mathcal{L}_{M}\right]\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x.
\end{equation}
Is it correct to say that the background independence condition lies in the fact that $g$ is the only variable that can appear in the action? What is the difference between this, and a general-covariant action of this form?
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{S_{\phi}}[\phi, \nabla_{\mu}\phi] = \int\frac{\sqrt{-g}}{2}\left(\nabla_{\mu}\phi\nabla^{\mu}\phi + m^{2}\phi^{2}\right)d^{4}x.
\end{equation}
Does this mean that when matter couples to gravity, a general-covariant description is not good enough, but instead we should require background independence? And that in order to make this change, we should remove any field dependency from the action, and add the $\frac{1}{8\pi}(R - 2\Lambda)$ lagrangian to it?

This could sound counterintuitive but the background independence condition means that the dynamics of a field depend on the background. I am gonna explain myself:
Classical Field Theory
Assume we have a collection of N fields $\Psi_A$, their dynamics is described, in field theory, by the action associated to the fields.
This action could depende on the fields and their derivatives, so is encoded in:
$$S=S[\Psi_A, d\Psi_A, ...]$$
Where "d" is a differential operator to be specified, both by geometry and gauge fields eventually present.
This is not not the full story tho, since we did not provide the context of which space is the one where the fields live.
To do this, we must provide a geometry (a background).
Background (Fixed) Independent Field Theory
Usually when the action is written as:
$$S=S[\Psi_A, d\Psi_A, ...]$$
One assumes that the geometry of the background is a (Lorentzian) flat geometry.
To obtain a description which does account for the geometry one usually should "incorporate" a dependence with respect to the geometry inside the action:
$$S=S[\Psi_A(g), d_g \Psi_A(g), ...]$$
In this way the dynamics is not only specified by the fields configurations, but also by the geometry on which those configurations live: allowing the dynamics to depend on the geometry, encoded by "g", we assured the fact that our solution is independentement of any background: the solution must hold for ALL backgrounds since every metric is allowed.
The presence of the metric modifies the derivative acting on the fields as well as the fields scalar products, effectively changing the dynamics of the fields.
Notice that even if the metric is undetermined, in this scenario is a considered fixed: one can consider whatever geometry, but only one at time.
Background (Dynamical) Independent Field Theory
To allow geometry changes, and hence geometrodynamics, when must consider the metric "g" as a dynamical field itself, so inside the action should also appear a term adeguate to encode the dynamics:
$$S=S[g, d_gg,...\Psi_A, d_g \Psi_A, ...]$$
To derive from this action the dynamics of the fields one takes the functional derivatives with respect to the fields and their derivatives, while to derive the dynamics of the metric one consider functional derivatives of the metric. There is no surprise in this: this is the same procedure as the other fields, since we said that we consider now "g" as a dynamical field itself!

EXPANSION AFTER EDIT
Lets see this in detail. I will suppress the derivatives in $S[...]$ for readability.
To see how the metric, i.e. the background geometry, evolves dinamically one must study the equation of motion associated to the metric itself:
$$0=\frac{\delta S[g, \Psi_A]}{\delta g}$$
This is equivalent to te Einstein equations in the presence of matter fields (the derivative gets contribution from the matter terms where the metric appears)
One also needs to solve the equations of motion for the $N$ fields in order to see how they evolve, and this is done by solving:
$$0=\frac{\delta S[g, \Psi_A]}{\delta \Psi_A}\qquad \forall A=1,...,N$$
To have the full dynamics of $N+1$ fields one should solve the system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\delta S[g, \Psi_A]}{\delta g}=0\qquad\text{Metric Evolution}\\
\frac{\delta S[g, \Psi_A]}{\delta \Psi_1}=0\qquad\text{Field 1 Evolution}\\
\frac{\delta S[g, \Psi_A]}{\delta \Psi_2}=0\qquad\text{Field 2 Evolution}\\
...\\
\frac{\delta S[g, \Psi_A]}{\delta \Psi_N}=0\qquad\text{Field N Evolution}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
This is how background independent classical field theory is done.

On the Einstein-Hilber action
In the context of your post, the $R-2\Lambda$ term is the dynamical term appropriate for the metric field of general relativity, and must be added only if one desires the metric to be a dynamical entity which behaves under the rules of general relativity. Its the equivalent of $(\partial\phi)^2$ for free scalar field theories in flat spacetime.
Generically you have a lagrangian density for the metric, which is $\mathcal{L}_{EH}[g, d_gg,...]$, and a lagrangian density for matter, $\mathcal{L}_M[g,\Psi_A, d_g\Psi_A,...]$.
The first one is the lagrangian for a dynamical spacetime, given by you $R-2\Lambda$, and this depends only on the metric field and derivatives.
The second lagrangian is the one for dynamical fields ON spacetime, and depend on both the fields and the metric.
If you remove the first lagrangian but keep the second, you don't have anymore a dynamical spacetime but a background independent field theory (the g-dependence in $\mathcal{L}_M$!) on a fixed arbitrary spacetime.
If you remove the first lagrangian AND the g-dependence from the matter lagrangian you simply have a field theory on a given background, not valid for an arbitrary one. An example of this are classical Minkowsky field theories: the equations of motion are valid only on Minkowsky spacetimes and generally do not hold for other geometries, with some exceptions.

So, in the last action you wrote, one has to derive two equations of motion? Because I thought that in GR one only has variation with respect to the metric, even in the presence of the matter lagrangian

@Davyz2 i have expanded my answer to clarify how the dynamics work better
